# Swift LocalNotifications not firing

Tags: swift, notifications

I'm trying to execute a local notification in Swift with the following code:

```
  private func scheduleBGNotifications(result: FlutterResult) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("All set!")
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Wake up!", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Rise and shine! It's morning time!",arguments: nil)
      let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      let notificationDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(30))
      let component = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year, .hour,.minute,.second], from: notificationDate)
      print(component)
      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: component, repeats: false)
      let request: UNNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "positiveAffirmation", content: content, trigger: trigger)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
          if let _ = error {
              print("Failed to schedule notifications")
              assertionFailure()
          } else {
              print("Notification scheduled!")
          }
      }
  }
```

I have set `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I'm running the code on real device, and exit the app after it opens up, but the notification still doesn't fire. I have all the permissions and have received remote notification from this app in the past, but this one doesn't work. `All set!` and `Notification scheduled!` both get printed. For context, It's a flutter project, but I call this function through a Method channel.

Comment: 1) All of your code to create and post the notification needs to be inside the completion block to `requestAuthorization`. 2) Each notification you create needs its own unique identifier. You are using the same identifier every time. 3) Update your question with the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` you implemented in your app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is purely a Flutter issue? The following non-Flutter version of your code works fine for me.

[image]

The main changes are that (1) I have thrown away your useless declaration of `notificationCenter` and (2) unlike you, I have grappled with the fact that `requestAuthorization` is asynchronous. Also it is, as you rightly imply, necessary to switch out of the app (i.e. background it) if you want to *see* evidence that the notification is firing, as there will be no such evidence if the notification fires when the app is in the foreground.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scheduleNotification()
    }
    func scheduleNotification() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
            if success {
                print("All set!")
                self.proceed()
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    func proceed() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Wake up!", arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Rise and shine! It's morning time!",arguments: nil)
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let notificationDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(30))
        let component = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year, .hour,.minute,.second], from: notificationDate)
        print(component)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: component, repeats: false)
        let request: UNNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "positiveAffirmation", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in
            if let _ = error {
                print("Failed to schedule notifications")
                assertionFailure()
            } else {
                print("Notification scheduled!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - an app can have local notifications appear even while the app is in the foreground. I have an app that does this. The docs cover this at [Handling notifications and notification-related actions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions) under the "Handle notifications while your app runs in the foreground" section about 3/4 down the page. In my case I call the completion handler with the `.banner` and `.list` options.

Comment: FYI - I know that. But the OP's question doesn't include code to make that happen. So, as it stands, the OP would indeed need to background the app to see the banner shown in my screenshot.

Comment: I'm confused then since your answer states: *"Also it is, as you rightly imply, necessary to switch out of the app (i.e. background it) if you want to see evidence that the notification is firing, as there will be no such evidence if the notification fires when the app is in the foreground."*. I took that to mean you thought, in general, that an app couldn't display its own local notifications while in the foreground. So I pointed out that the banner can appear even while the app is in the foreground if the proper delegate method is implemented with the proper options.

Comment: Might be a Flutter issue, I copied your code and it still didn't fire.